# The result of this sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the result of this sum

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot n^2 \;?$

And I have also tried the root test, but it gives me $1,$ so I can't use it, and also the alternating test is not useful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It diverges

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you for answering but according to what theorem or what test ?

Comment: A necessary (but not sufficient) condition for an infinite sum to be convergent is that the sequence of its general terms (a_n) converges to zero. This is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty -(2k-1)^2+(2k)^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(4k-1).$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I didn't understand how did you assume that n =2k    and how did you ignore the -1??

Comment: I replaced odd $n$ with $2k-1$ and even $n$ with $2k$

Comment: And what's about the (-1)^n ????

Comment: $(-1)^{2k-1}=-1$ and $(-1)^{2k}=1$

Comment: Now what I see is that it approaches negative and positive infinity in the same time is that right ?

Comment: Partial sums alternate between positive and negative, and their magnitude grows without bound

Comment: @YyyUuu in case it still isn't clear what JWTanner did., rather than looking at $-1+4-9+16-25+36-49+64\pm\dots$ he looked at $(-1+4)+(-9+16)+(-25+36)+(-49+64)+\dots$, having grouped and summed the sums of consecutive terms (*which that the result diverges implies the original diverges as well.  one should be careful here however since if having done this causes the manipulated sum to converge this doesn't imply the original converges... take $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ for instance*)

Comment: "Now what I see is that it approaches negative and positive infinity in the same time is that right ?"  You can put it like that but I will nit pick that 1) things can not "approach" infinity and 2) things can not approach two values "at the same time".  For even terms the partial sums are positive and for odd terms the partial sums are negative and in either case they are unbounded.  ... I suspect you are assuming you are expected to say more about every series then you will be able to or be required to say.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges, by the Divergence Test (if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges).

Let $a_n=(-1)^nn^2$ and calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^nn^2$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2$$

We see that neither limit converges to a value. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$; and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2$ goes to infinity. Clearly $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, and so the series diverges.